# Rollback in Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

I am having a problem in Oracle rollback.

In my stored procedure I have multiple insert and update statements.
If every thing is fine I am sending success message and also I am tracing success status into one Z_AUDIT_HISTORY table.

Now same thing I need in fail status also first need to rollback all statements then track fail status into this Z_AUDIT_HISTORY table.

My procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SPTest
AS 
BEGIN 
  SAVEPOINT sp_sptest;

  insert into emptest(empid,empname,deptno)
  (1,'ravi',10);

  insert into test1(id,name,sal)
  (1,'raju',4444);

  update emptest set empname='hari' where empid=1;

  INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT_HISTORY(AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID,STATUS)
  VALUES(SEQ_AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID.NEXTVAL,'SUCESS');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sucess');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT_HISTORY(AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID,ASSET_ID,STATUS)
    VALUES(SEQ_AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID.NEXTVAL,p_asset_id,'FAIL');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Whoops');

    ROLLBACK TO sp_sptest;

    RAISE; 
END;
```

When I execute my procedure I am getting below error.

```
ORA-06512: at line 1
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things going on here.

1. When handling the exception, you do an insert followed by a rollback. That means *that* insert is rolled back as well. At the very least, switch the order of the statements:

   ```
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Whoops');

   ROLLBACK TO sp_sptest;

   INSERT INTO Z_AUDIT_HISTORY(AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID,ASSET_ID,STATUS)
   VALUES(SEQ_AUDIT_HISTORTY_ID.NEXTVAL,p_asset_id,'FAIL');

   RAISE;
   ```
2. Better yet, handle logging in an autonomous transaction. That means that it's a separate transaction that is not affected by anything happening in the main transaction. For logging, you want this.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_audit(
      p_asset_id NUMBER,
      p_status VARCHAR
   ) AS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO z_audit_history(audit_history_id, asset_id, status)
      VALUES(seq_audit_history_id.NEXTVAL, p_asset_id, p_status);
   END;
   ```

   And call it

   ```
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Whoops');

   ROLLBACK TO sp_sptest;

   log_audit(p_asset_id, 'FAIL');

   RAISE;
   ```
3. You get an error because you raise the exception after doing the rollback.

   > **This is a good thing!**

   You do not want the exception to disappear silently, you want to know about it.

   What you *can* do, is handle the exceptions you're expecting. For instance, if you know an `ORA-06512` may occur and you know what you need to do in that case, you may add a specific handler for that situation, either in your stored procedure, or in the code that calls it.

Comment: Thank U very much ,for this , so what can i do , if i want to know the exception. so what type of  handler i need.